# What is the solution to this integral?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$\int \frac{x dx}{\sqrt{ax^{2} + bx + c}}$

with the following conditions:
$a < 0$,
$b > 0$,
$c < 0$,
and
$\left|2ax + b\right| > \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$.

I've tried looking this up on the internet and in books of integrals, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried completing the square first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for trigonometric substitution. Complete the square under the root to get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-a}}\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-(x-\beta)^2}}dx$$

Then the substitution $(x-\beta)= \alpha \sin(t)$ should work.

Comment: I did try that, but I couldn't get $|2ax+b|>\sqrt{b^2−4ac}$ condition, only $|2ax+b|<\sqrt{b^2−4ac}$. It doesn't matter though, since when I rechecked my calculations, the value for x that didn't satisfy $|2ax+b|<\sqrt{b^2−4ac}$ was wrong, and the right value did (it's the solution to a physics problem and the value was one that can't occur).

Answer (score 2):

Put it this way

$$\int {\frac{x}{{\sqrt {a{x^2} + bx + c} }}dx}  = \frac{1}{{2a}}\int {\frac{{2ax + b}}{{\sqrt {a{x^2} + bx + c} }}dx}  - \frac{b}{{2a}}\int {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {a{x^2} + bx + c} }}} $$

Then

$$\int {\frac{x}{{\sqrt {a{x^2} + bx + c} }}dx}  = \frac{1}{a}\sqrt {a{x^2} + bx + c}  - \frac{b}{{2a}}\int {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {a{x^2} + bx + c} }}} $$

So let's focus on the last integral.

$$a{x^2} + bx + c = a\left[ {{{\left( {x + \frac{b}{{2a}}} \right)}^2} + \frac{c}{a} - \frac{{{b^2}}}{{4{a^2}}}} \right]$$

Thus by making $${x + \frac{b}{{2a}}} = u$$

we have a new polynomial to integrate. Consider the cases:

1. $\displaystyle \frac{c}{a} - \frac{{{b^2}}}{{4{a^2}}} < 0 =  - {k^2}$. So you have:

   $$\frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}\int {\frac{{du}}{{\sqrt {{u^2} - {k^2}} }}}  =  \frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}\cosh^{-1} \frac{u}{k}$$
2. $\displaystyle \frac{c}{a} - \frac{{{b^2}}}{{4{a^2}}} = 0$. You get

$$\frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}\int {\frac{{du}}{u}}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}\log u$$

1. $\displaystyle \frac{c}{a} - \frac{{{b^2}}}{{4{a^2}}} > 0 = {k^2}$

$$\frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}\int {\frac{{du}}{{\sqrt {{u^2} + {k^2}} }}}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}{\sinh ^{ - 1}}\frac{u}{k}$$

So it all depends on the polynomial.

Comment: Since $a<0$ and assumedly $b^2-4ac>0$ (since the OP mentions $|2ax+b|>\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$, and $>$ is hard to define on $\mathbb{C}$), I would think a trig substitution would be better here.